# Mapping of one collection to another in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a collection of objects, which I want to map to another collection, doing similar routine operations for every element. I'd like to do these atomic routine operations in parallel threads and looking for some ready-to-use library that can help me:

```
Collection<X> source = // ...
Collection<Y> result = Threader.map(
  source,
  new Mapping<X, Y>() {
    @Override
    public Y map(X src) {
      // do something and return an instance of Y
    }
  }
);
```

I understand that it's easy to implement but I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Do you know any libraries that contain such a `Threader` class?

I think that [Java 8 streams](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/collections-overview.html) are going to do something similar to this...

I submitted a feature request to Guava: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1422

Comment: I think that you are looking for [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). Or if you are looking for an alternative on [this site](http://www.bytemining.com/2011/08/hadoop-fatigue-alternatives-to-hadoop/) you may find one.

Comment: Is there a reason a java.util.concurrent.Executor (ExecutorService) wouldn't do what you need?
That's the easiest way to run parallel operations, although you'd have to do the break-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [functionaljava](http://functionaljava.org/) library may do what you want.   It provides its own collection types that you can convert to/from java.util.Collection.   The collection types have map operations for which you can provide your own functions, and a concurrency stategy for that mapping.  There's a good blog posting on using functionaljava for parallel list processing here:

http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2008/06/30/parallel-list-transformations/